# SP2013 Display template , slider

Tags: display-template, template

I have used content query search web part & applied slideshow but that is not working properly. I am trying to create a news slider with big image which will come from a list , it is showing title of the list but not image & line 2  so is there anyway I can do that I have tried to edit the control template but not getting what to do & where to go or I have to used use external slider which are available on net ?? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i you  share  slideshow code ?

Comment: it is in sharepoint only go in site settings -> design manager -> upload design files -> your mapped drive -> catalogs-> master pages-> display template-> content web parts -> slide show